# Python PPT: Unable to create a regular paragraph with bold heading and regular text

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-pptx

Hi i am trying to write something a very simple paragraph on a ppt slide.

```
shapes3 = slide4.shapes
shapes3.title.text = 'Hypothesis:Overinvested Categories?'

textbox = shapes3.add_textbox(Inches(3), Inches(1.5),Inches(3), Inches(1))

bullet_point_lvl1 = shapes3.placeholders[1]
bullet_point_lvl1.text= dfh.iat[9,0]+":"+ dfh.iat[9,2] +" text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text" 

bullet_point_lvl2 = bullet_point_lvl1.text_frame.add_paragraph()
bullet_point_lvl2.text = "text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text "
bullet_point_lvl2 = 2
```

[image]

Desired output

[image]

Comment: Can anyone help me to write simple text on ppt slides.

Comment: Have a look at the first page of the documentation here: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and the example there starting with `p.add_run()`. Basically, add the "Blockchain ..." bit as one run, set it bold, and add the rest as another run.